The b'rachah on sardines in tomato sauce
Which brachah should you say before eating a can of sardines in tomato sauce, and why?
The sardines taste good, but the tomato sauce tastes good too.

A.) The ikar here is definitely the fish. This is clear even from the name of the product. You're not eating sardine-flavored tomato sauce: you're eating sardines which are pleasantly complemented by the tomato sauce.
B.) Although there is an argument that you could make ha'adama on tomato sauce, most people make shehakol.
Conclusion: the blessing is shehakol
Considering A.) and B.) above, the bracha on sardines in tomato sauce is definitely shehakol.
